# Stackoverflow Exception при инициализации базового класса, в чем проблема?

Tags: c#, исключения

Выдает исключение `StackOverflowException` при такой конструкции:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Инициализация базового класса
      var a = new A(); <<< тут исключение
}

private class A
{
      public B b = new B();
      public C c = new C();
}

private class B : A
{

}

private class C : A
{

}
```

Почему?

Answer (score 10):

Для начала, в Вашем случае, объявление полей класса с их немедленной инициализацией

```
private class A
{
      public B b = new B();
      public C c = new C();
}
```

компилятор превращает в

```
private class A
{
      public B b;
      public C c;

      public A()
      {
          b = new B();
          c = new C();
      }
}
```

Т.е. если вы явно не создаете конструктор, то за Вас его создат компилятор и добавит туда инициализацию этих полей.

Теперь давайте посмотрим что будет происходить при создании экземпляра класса `A`.

При создании эземпляра вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, в котором инициализируется два поля `b = new B()` и `c = new C()`. `B` и `C` наследуются от `A` и, соответственно (т.к. Вы не указали конструктор для них) вызывается родительский контсруктор по умолчанию, в котором, опять же, инициализируются эти два поля (точнее скорее всего до инициализации `c` дело даже не дойдет, т.к. все свалится на инициализации `b`, но не уверен). Таким образом мы падаем в бесконечную инициализацию и получаем `StackoverflowException`

Comment: Насколько я знаю, инициализация полей, при таком коде, будет происходить ДО вызова конструктора, т.е. будет его предварять. Так что технически некорректно говорить, что код будет таким, как Вы привели, хотя конкретно для этого вопроса это и не важно

Comment: @ixSci с точки зрения C# - инициализация полей происходит до вызова конструктора. С точки зрения CLR - в конструкторе.