# Как объявить наследники дочерних классов в базовом?

Tags: c#, .net

В продолжении этого вопроса: [Stackoverflow Exception при инициализации базового класса, в чем проблема?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504080/stackoverflow-exception-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Каким образом можно объявить публичными полями в базовом классе - классы наследники?

Пробовал в классах-наследниках создать собственные конструкторы - но ошибка не пропала.

Comment: можете объяснить зачем вам это надо? какую задачу вы таким способом хотите решить? Базовый класс в принципе не обязан знать о наследниках

Comment: Сообщить классам-наследникам о других классах-наследниках через базовый класс.

Comment: Т.е. есть базовый класс A, есть классы-наследники B и  C. Я хочу организовать доступ из класса B к полю\методу класса C через класс А.

Comment: Я на 100% уверен, что вашу задачу можно решить без этого. Но, в любом случае, проблема с инициализацей полей в конструкторе - просто не инициализируйте их в конструкторе и все.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь почесать левой пяткой правое ухо. Расскажите нам о более высокоуровневой задаче. Или как минимум примите за факт, что посредником между В и С должен быть не А, а некоторый четвертый класс-посредник. Можете погуглить "шаблон посредник".

Comment: А вынести, то ради чего весь этот огород, в интерфейс нельзя или не пробовали?

Comment: > Т.е. есть базовый класс A, есть классы-наследники B и C. Я хочу организовать доступ из класса B к полю\методу класса C через класс А.     А какие отношения между A, B, C? Всмысле, равноправные, A - общий прародитель некий или вообще цепочка A -> B -> C?

Comment: @Monk, посмотри ссылку в вопросе - там дан код иерархии

Comment: @Grundy интересует логика, а не наследование

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж у нас в руках молоток и все кажется гвоздем, давайте все-таки забьем.

В качестве обходного решения можно использовать [класс Lazy<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx), который позволит нам отложить вызов конструкторов и разобьет бесконечную рекурсию.

```
class A
{
    private Lazy<B> b;
    private Lazy<C> c;

    public B B { get { return b.Value; } }
    public C C { get { return c.Value; } }

    public A()
    {
        b = new Lazy<B>();
        c = new Lazy<C>();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com

Comment: @andreycha, но ведь работает же :-D

Comment: Простите, но поставлю ответу минус. Нужно все-таки стараться на пусть истинный наставлять.

Comment: @andreycha, это да :-) но обходные пути тоже иногда нужны :)

Comment: @andreycha, не будьте столь категоричный. Дайте свой ответ, а Grundy дополнит свой, что такой метод нужно использовать в крайнем случает. Нужно ведь всесторонне развиваться.

Comment: @Alexis, там уже есть слова _В качестве обходного решения_, что как бы намекает, что это не решает проблему :) а давать другой ответ нельзя так как неизвестно какую же все-таки задачу пытается решить автор

Comment: В каждом B и C будут такие же поля, и авторское "хочу из B в C обращаться" не выполняется. Потому как нечем же =)